# Is it possible to fake the Android version to allow ROM downgrading?

Tags: samsung, rom, android-versions, downgrade

I was trying to downgrade an Android 11 on Samsung Galaxy A01 Cricket (SM-A015AZ), but cannot because the download mode doesn't let me install an older ROM. So the plan is somehow to modify the info of the old ROM to "lie" about the version to appear as a recent ROM, but it is still in fact, an old ROM.

Already spent a lot of hours searching on Google. Only found how to create a custom ROM from zero or how to modify ROMs from Android 1 to Android 7.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: downgrade protection is for bootloader level (and can't be by-passed at all)